# What happen if QTimer doesn't stop

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimer

I have a question that: How about memory or something else happen if I start a QTimer but don't stop it.

This is my code:
File a.h

```
void updateProgressBar()
```

File a.cpp

```
void updateProgressBar(){
timer= new QTimer(this);
timer->setInterval(1000);
timer->setSingleShot(false);
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),
        myMainUi,
        SLOT(setProgressBar()));
timer->start();
}
```

File Main.cpp

```
int main(){
     while(1){
        updateProgressBar();
    }
return 1;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The documentation seems pretty clear in this case -- the `QTimer` will fire every `interval` seconds when `singleShot` is set to false. That said, the lifecycle of your `QTimer` object is not clear based on the code you've posted.

Comment: if you need to update progress bar, why do you create QTimer again and again..?

Comment: @MrEricSir So how about memory ?

Comment: @Ashif Because It bases on time of playing clip.

Comment: you can play clip using one timer, by updating the timer you created once. But in your code you are creating timer infinite loop...this will popup heap memory and crash the application.

Comment: your code dont have sens... if your demand is about QProgressBar, note that if we set value outside min,max range the set dont have any effect. also there is not slot called setProgressBar() and like mentioned by @Ashif your program will crash before seeing progress bar.

Comment: Memory thing is simple: you create `new QTimer` every time, so that's going to eat more and more memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QTimer is fired from the Qt internal event loop.

Your code will create an infinite number of QTimer and will eventually crash.

If you program using Qt, you will avoid having an infinite loop as while (1), this wouldn't work as it will block Qt event loop.

Given that you seem to have an UI, your code should be within a class, in which case it would make more sense to declare your QTimer in the class definition as a private member and not as a pointer, then initialise it on the constructor.

```
class MyClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void startUpdateProgressBar() { 
        myTimer.singleShot(false);
        myTimer.start(1000);
    }

    void stopUpdateProgressBar() { 
        myTimer.stop();
    }

  private:
        QTimer myTimer;
};
```